# Rails, how to .sort with conditional logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, conditional-statements

I have an issue I've as of yet been unable to solve, as `.sort_by` is depreciating in Rails 5.1 I am required to change any of these methods in my current project into `.sort` I am still learning Rails so I apoligise if this is an easy solution.

My use case is: 
`items = items.sort_by{ |a, b| [a.updated_at > current_user.news_seen_at ? 0 : 1, now - a.updated_at] }`

I believe I understand that this currently is sorting by an array of [0, *some time*] OR [1, *some time*].
My question is, how do I go about re-writing this to use `.sort`? Is it possible to include conditional logic like there already is, or is that required to be done before the `sort` to allow for a simple `.sort{ |a,b| a <=> b}`? 
 Any suggestions, guidance and/or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell what class `items` is that `sort_by` is deprecated? If this where a normal array `sort_by` would work fine. What does `items.class` give back?

Comment: @3limin4t0r `items` is an array that's initialized in the index of a **news** controller. The items are notifications/news items in a users notification feed page. Thank-you for providing a possible solution however I am required to remove `sort_by` and use a different method.

Comment: If you're required to remove the `sort_by` call it means you're not working with an array. Since [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) is still alive and well in the newest Ruby 2.7. I believe you think you're working with an array, but in reality it's something different. Did `items.class` give back `Array`?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Hmmm maybe I still have a lot to learn!
`def index
        items = []
        items = items + BlogPost.where
        items = items + Friendship.left_joins`
... etc.

This is how it's defined in the controller. Doing items.class returns an error, `undefined local variable or method`

Comment: what is your source where you saw sort_by is being deprecated?

Comment: I used `sort_by` today~

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass a block to `sort`.
See https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort.

For clarity: `sort_by` is a Ruby method and is still there on the latest version.
A specific Rails release would not deprecate something on Ruby.

Here is the doc for `sort_by`: https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by